# NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bach1", withExtension: "jpg") returning null

Tags: swift

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bach1", withExtension: "jpg")
```

The above code is returning null.

In order to check if the file exists or not, I used below code:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(savepath) {
  println("exist")
}
```

The above code returns that file exists in directory.

So I don't understand why the first code is returning null

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bach1", withExtension: "jpg") returns an optional NSURL. You need to use if let to unwrap it and extract your file path from the returned url as follow:

```
if let resourceUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bach1", withExtension: "jpg") {
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(resourceUrl.path!) {
        print("file found")
    }
}
```

Comment: with this snippet, I never print "file found", the resourceUrl is always nil. I have the file in my app bundle, but it does not see it

Comment: Probably your file it is not Bundled with your app. If you saved your file to the documents folder you need to get that folder url and append the file name you are trying to load to the folder url

Answer (score 8):

> **Swift 3.x**

```
if let resourceUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "bach1", withExtension: "jpg") {
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: resourceUrl.path) {
        print("file found")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that you have to actually go into Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources and manually add your item sometimes to the bundle. In my case it was a video file that didn't get added to the bundle correctly on its own.

Answer (score 2):

`NSBundle.URLForResource` only returns files that are bundled in your application at build/compile time, like when you drag a file into your Xcode project and add it to your app target. You can typically use this when your app comes preloaded with resources you need, like images, movies, databases, and other files.

It seems like `savepath` is a path your application wrote to while running (maybe into your app's Documents directory?). Because of this, the file is outside of the bundle and you will need to store that path/URL somewhere (or build it up again) if you need to reference the file in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too. My fix was:

- Selecting the file in project navigator
- Open the 'File Inspector' (on the right hand side pane)
- Checking the app target in the Target Membership