# Fatal Error with NSURL ofType MP4

Tags: xcode, swift, video, nsurl

When I build and run my project I get a fatal error (see image below). I believe there is a problem with the `NSURL` but unsure what part is wrong. I have replaced the video with a different video and it works. There is not a problem with the video as I have played it in Quick Time Player. [image]

Hope someone can help!

Comment: You should use NSBundle method URLForResource

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28750856/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus that doesnt explain the BAD_EXC, because let url type could be `NSUrl?`, right? But the link is good. Also check that the ressource name is the right one.

Comment: If i knew the reason I would post an answer not a comment suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file it is in the proper format. Use your finder to get info of your file and check if the More Info: Codecs: it is showing H.264, AAC.

Answer (score 0):

The .mp4 file is missing from the main bundle. I was able to replicate the exact error code in the Playground.
[image]

Now with the .mp4 file in the main bundle.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your video was probably not added correctly to the main Bundle. Here is how to get it right :

- Click on your project (blue icon) and select the appropriate target
- Go to Build Phases
- Look for "Copy Bundle Resources"
- If your video doesn't appear here, click the "+" icon and add it
- Don't forget to check out the other answerds/comment about unwrapping the URL that might be an optional

Et voilà !

Comment: Just tried it. I have added it to the "Copy Bundle Resources" and still nothing. Thanks for your help though 

Comment: @JohnGool you should make sure the file it is in the proper format. Use your finder to get info of your file and check if the More Info: Codecs: it is showing H.264, AAC

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks! Just changed the codecs on the video, now working. Thanks a lot for your help! 

Comment: @JohnGool you are welcome. Just posted the previous comment as the answer. Fell free to accept it or just delete your question.

Comment: @LeoDabus I have accepted the answer as it is a valid answer. Thanks!